# JQuery Dialog and Background Freezing

Tags: jquery, dialog

I would like to freeze the background while a jquery dialog box appears. I am using the code below for dialog box.

$("#divGroup").dialog

({

```
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 450,
        resizable: false,
        position: [500, 200],
```

});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the modal property to true.

```
 autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 450,
        width: 450,
        resizable: false,
        position: [500, 200],
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where in the css jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css I can find the css class that support this modal property? I would like to take that specific code to my main css.

Comment: OK I found that.
/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-disabled { cursor: default !important; }

/* Misc visuals
/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }